# Can one hero use multiple Toryn Gauntlets?

Tags: thunderstone-dragonspire

**Toryn Gauntlet** allows a hero to wield an additional weapon.  Can another gauntlet be wielded?  How about a third?

Comment: This is a bit like in Magic the Gathering where you can equip human-sized helmets and swords to birds and insects and so on.  My favourite online "interpretation" of three Toryn Gauntlets is a hero wearing two of them and using the third to slap the enemy in the face, challenge-to-a-duel style!  +1 for the image of an awesome three-armed adventurer, anyway...

Comment: @thesunneversets yes, but since they're only made for one hand, one has to stack them when wearing them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can equip multiple Toryn Gauntlets to one hero, adding the benefits together. Note also that you do not add together the weights of the various weapons - each weapon's weight is compared to the hero's strength individually, so a hero of strength 2 could equip a gauntlet (weight 2, I believe - assume it's right for the example) and another weapon of weight 4 (2 strength from the hero base and 2 strength from the gauntlet).